# Express + Angular update route: Error: Cannot PUT

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to update a schema using form, however, both on app.put and app.post (which I've seen as a possible solution) i get

```
PUT https://myapp-demo.herokuapp.com/api/events/5523da4d97c5000300f6e713 404 (Not Found)
```

and error from ajax callback

```
Error: Cannot PUT /api/events/5523da4d97c5000300f6e713
```

on clientside, I make this request:

```
$scope.saveEvent = function(id) {
  $http.put('../api/events/' + id, $scope.formData)
          .success(function (data) {
              $scope.events = data;
          })
          .error(function(data) {
              console.log('Error: ' + data);
          })
};
```

In express routes, I do this:

```
app.put('../api/events/:id', function (req, res){
    var user = req.user;
    var id = req.params.id;
    var update = {
        $set: {
                title: req.body.title,
                description: req.body.description,
              }
    };

        Event.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, function (err, event) {
            if(!event) {
                res.statusCode = 404;
                return res.send({ error: 'Not found' });
            }
            console.log("event updated");
            Event.find(function(err, events) {
               if (err){
                  res.send(err)
              };
               res.json(events);
            });
        });
});
```

I tried to pass event._id differently, by using req.params.id and passing id with form like req.body.id, it all leads to the same result. I've also read about creating hidden input for helping method-override to override form methods. However, having this didn't help.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="saveEvent(eventId)">Save</md-button>
```

**UPDATE**

Indeed, the initial proble was in my put route. I've found a new problem now. When I try to update it again, I get

```
Error:  Object {error: "Not found"}
```

It happens even after I refresh page or restart server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is invalid:

```
app.put('../api/events/:id'...
```

It needs to be in reference to the namespace, or in your case the root:

```
app.put('/api/events/:id'...
```